# wait-on not moving onto the next command for my electron app using reactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, concurrently

I am new to electronjs and I am working on an electron app using ReactJs and I am trying to open the dev server using concurrently and wait-on.

Here is my scripts section of package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron:serve": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"npm run electron:start\"",
    "electron:build": "npm run build && electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js",
    "electron:start": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron .",
  },
```

And when I run `npm run electron:serve`, the I'm getting this on my terminal

[image]

The command doesn't seem to move on to the next section. And when I run `electron:start` on a new terminal I'm getting this

[image]

I had no problem running this on my old laptop two months back and it is not working now. It works fine when I run `npm start` and `electron .`.

I've been stuck on this for a while now and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add `-v` after `wait-on` to enable debug logs and share the error you get.

Comment: I keep getting this message over and over again on the terminal
 ```[1] making TCP connection to 3000 ...
[1]   error connecting to TCP host:localhost port:3000 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000```

Comment: Are you using Node v17?

Comment: I' m using `v18.12.1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will make a guess here. According to the discussions on [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40702) on GitHub, Node 17 introduced a breaking change that might trigger the error you get:

```
Error connecting to TCP host:localhost port:3000 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
```

Adding `127.0.0.1` to your script should work:

```
"electron:start": "wait-on tcp:127.0.0.1:3000 && electron ."
```