# Electron not opening my react project in a desktop window even after successful compilation

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have been trying to open my react project with `Electron`. However, the app opens on a browser but doesn't open in a windows app.

**My package.json file --**

```
"main": "public/electron.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"npm:electron\"",
    "electron": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron ."
  },
```

My electron.js file in the public folder --

```
const path = require('path');

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  // win.loadFile("index.html");
  win.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? 'http://localhost:3000'
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`
  );
  // Open the DevTools.
  if (isDev) {
    win.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' });
  }
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    app.quit();
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

**I have installed all the necessary packages and the compilation is successful.** However, it doesn't open any window when i run `npm run dev` in the terminal. Why is that happening?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/74651669/16196434

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wait-on not moving onto the next command for my electron app using reactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74615631/wait-on-not-moving-onto-the-next-command-for-my-electron-app-using-reactjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered this problem. But what I did is in the **Package.json** file I changed the code from this

```
"electron": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron ."
```

to this

```
"electron": "electron ."
```

The window will open but it's going to be blank. You have to reload the window once the react is done building. I don't have other way to solve this. But this is the best that I can share.